# Server-Info command for a bot

Tags: python, command, discord, discord.py

I want to add a Server Info command for my discord bot if anyone has it please submit the code :).

Comment: [How to ask good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) You should look this.

Answer (score 4):

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild
You can get the guild (discord server) by using:

```
client.get_guild(guild_ID)
```

And then you can get all the different info by using guild.name, guild.icon, ...

Answer (score 2):

I used this code, it should work for what you want. Although I would prefer a more detailed question, that way I could answer in a better format.

The `guild` variable can describe the server or the place that the command was used.

Then you just add your things like the server `id` etc.

I think you can also add roles to this on the list but for now, here is the code I used.

```py
@client.command()
async def serverinfo(ctx):
  name = str(ctx.guild.name)
  description = str(ctx.guild.description)

  owner = str(ctx.guild.owner)
  id = str(ctx.guild.id)
  region = str(ctx.guild.region)
  memberCount = str(ctx.guild.member_count)

  icon = str(ctx.guild.icon_url)
   
  embed = discord.Embed(
      title=name + " Server Information",
      description=description,
      color=discord.Color.blue()
    )
  embed.set_thumbnail(url=icon)
  embed.add_field(name="Owner", value=owner, inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="Server ID", value=id, inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="Region", value=region, inline=True)
  embed.add_field(name="Member Count", value=memberCount, inline=True)

  await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

p.s. I am a beginner at python and discord.py so sorry if this did not help.

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else is looking for a good serverinfo command, here is how I wrote mine.

```py
format = "%a, %d %b %Y | %H:%M:%S %ZGMT"

@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def serverinfo(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        color = ctx.guild.owner.top_role.color
    )
    text_channels = len(ctx.guild.text_channels)
    voice_channels = len(ctx.guild.voice_channels)
    categories = len(ctx.guild.categories)
    channels = text_channels + voice_channels
    embed.set_thumbnail(url = str(ctx.guild.icon_url))
    embed.add_field(name = f"Information About **{ctx.guild.name}**: ", value = f":white_small_square: ID: **{ctx.guild.id}** \n:white_small_square: Owner: **{ctx.guild.owner}** \n:white_small_square: Location: **{ctx.guild.region}** \n:white_small_square: Creation: **{ctx.guild.created_at.strftime(format)}** \n:white_small_square: Members: **{ctx.guild.member_count}** \n:white_small_square: Channels: **{channels}** Channels; **{text_channels}** Text, **{voice_channels}** Voice, **{categories}** Categories \n:white_small_square: Verification: **{str(ctx.guild.verification_level).upper()}** \n:white_small_square: Features: {', '.join(f'**{x}**' for x in ctx.guild.features)} \n:white_small_square: Splash: {ctx.guild.splash}")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

The command will show the **server ID, owner, location, date created, members, channels, verification, features, and splash**.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I wrote mine

```
@commands.has_any_role('Owner', 'Head Dev', 'Head Admin', 'Admins', 'Moderator', 'Community Helper', 'Team Leader', 'Head Team Member')
async def serverinfo(self, ctx):

    role_count = len(ctx.guild.roles)
    list_of_bots = [bot.mention for bot in ctx.guild.members if bot.bot]
    staff_roles = ["Owner", "Head Dev", "Dev", "Head Admin", "Admins", "Moderators", "Community Helpers", "Members"]
        
    embed2 = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, color=ctx.author.color)
    embed2.add_field(name='Name', value=f"{ctx.guild.name}", inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Owner', value=f"Mekasu, Kastien", inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Verification Level', value=str(ctx.guild.verification_level), inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Highest role', value=ctx.guild.roles[-2], inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Contributers:', value="None")

    for r in staff_roles:
        role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name=r)
        if role:
            members = '\n'.join([member.name for member in role.members]) or "None"
            embed2.add_field(name=role.name, value=members)

    embed2.add_field(name='Number of roles', value=str(role_count), inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Number Of Members', value=ctx.guild.member_count, inline=False)
    embed2.add_field(name='Bots:', value=(', '.join(list_of_bots)))
    embed2.add_field(name='Created At', value=ctx.guild.created_at.__format__('%A, %d. %B %Y @ %H:%M:%S'), inline=False)
    embed2.set_thumbnail(url=ctx.guild.icon_url)
    embed2.set_author(name=ctx.author.name, icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
    embed2.set_footer(text=self.bot.user.name, icon_url=self.bot.user.avatar_url)

    channel = self.bot.get_channel(staff_commands)
    await channel.send(embed=embed2)
```

using [the docs here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=guild%20id#guild)